# How do I change the way NetBeans formats my JSON data?

Tags: json, formatting, netbeans-7

I'm using `NetBeans 7.2` and in my JavaScript files, I prefer to format my JSON like:

```
{text:'Serial Number: ',x:10, y:10, xtype:'label'},
{text:'Product Code: ',x:10, y:30, xtype:'label'},
....
```

But instead, when I apply the Format command (`Alt-Shift-F`), it formats it like:

```
{
    text:'Serial Number: ',
    x:10,
    y:10,
    xtype:'label'
},
{
    text:'Product Code: ',
    x:10, 
    y:30, 
    xtype:'label'
},
```

I've looked everywhere but the right place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `NetBeans 7.3` does exactly what I want.  While I wasn't able to figure out how to do a custom JSON format, 7.3 doesn't destroy my format nearly as much as 7.2 did.

Answer (score 3):

Under Netbeans 7.4 (and probably others) you need to:

1. Pick menu `Tools/Options`
2. Select the `Editor` section
3. Pick the `Formatting` tab
4. Select the `JSON` language
5. Adjust at will ... change category for further settings

[image: Sample settings]